# Connect to a network share using Android

Tags: java, android

I am an android developer.
I would like to connect to a network share (on my Windows\Mac\Linux machines).
I am familiar with few apps that achieve that, but I would like to know how to implement it.
I am interested in the code. Any help will be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you probably need Samba or CIFS to access Windows/Linux (don't know about Mac). What about Apache common VFS (http://commons.apache.org/vfs/filesystems.html#CIFS)